# Is there any way to intercept GET api response via selenium webdriver or rest api and make the response body null to check the error handling on UI?

Tags: java, selenium, rest

Is there any way to intercept GET API response via selenium web driver or rest API and make the response body null to check the error handling on UI?

Comment: You might check here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api/#network-interception

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this has been added in Selenium 4

```
NetworkInterceptor interceptor = new NetworkInterceptor(
      driver,
      Route.matching(req -> req.getUri().contains("myRequestUrl"))
        .to(() -> req -> new HttpResponse()
          .setStatus(200)
          .addHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.HTML_UTF_8.toString())
          .setContent(utf8String("Hello, World!"))));

driver.get("https://www.mywebsite.com");

String source = driver.getPageSource();

assertThat(source).contains("Hello, World!");
```

See [Network Interception](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api/#network-interception)